# STM32 - How to convert ADC (with DMA) sample number to time without assuming uniform conversion time?

Tags: stm32, adc, dma, stm32cubeide

I'm new to working with ADCs on STM32. I'm reading a rectified voltage using ADC with DMA on an STM32G0B1. I know the ADC conversion time from the datasheet but I want to compare the ADC's output with readings from an oscilloscope. I'm plotting the voltage captured on the oscilloscope for 0.5 s and wish to compare this with the ADC output.

I'm using the ADC in continuous conversion mode with DMA. The clock prescaler is set to "Synchronous clock mode divided by 2" and the sampling time is 1.5 cycles. I'm storing samples in a 2000-length buffer.

However, on the project I'm working, I'm being told not to assume uniform conversion time between samples. If that would've been the case, I would've directly converted the sample numbers (i.e. indices) to units in time. Rather, I'm told to measure the conversion time between samples using a timer (say TIM16). I have tested the conversion time for the DMA mode on an oscilloscope by setting a GPIO pin HIGH when the conversion is complete.

How can I measure the conversion time between samples so that I can plot the oscilloscope voltage and ADC output on the same graph? I know the timescales of both graphs would differ, but the fundamental objective is to convert the sample number to a dimension in time without assuming uniform conversion time. Would measuring the conversion time b/w samples (in microseconds) for the ADC with DMA using timers be the optimal approach? If yes, between which functions/events in `HAL_ADC_xx` should I trigger a timer?

Comment: Seems a bit strange. The ADC clock is pretty stable (I can't find the spec in the data sheet though), so there is no reason why the conversion time would change much between samples. You can also just trigger the conversions from a timer so they are sync'd to the system clock. If this is a crystal then you should easily be able to have very accurate sampling.

Comment: Another option is to just output the conversion triggers to a GPIO and then sample this with the oscilloscope on another channel so you can cross reference later (not sure if this fits with the way you're doing the measurements though).

Comment: Why ever not just use a timer to fire this off? Is this school work or something?

Comment: @Jon I agree that the ADC clock should be pretty stable. There are two reasons why my supervisor at work suggested to measure the conversion time between samples to calibrate/compare with the oscilloscope data: (1) There are other HW problems with the G0 (for example, USART2 TX/RX output is pulled up by 1 V w/o configuring it so, causing communication issues) and (2) To verify if the conversion time is consistent among samples. Thanks for your suggestions, I'll implement them (if need be).

Comment: I discussed this with the supervisor concerned and they suggested practically verifying conversion times by storing them using HAL_GetTick() in a buffer and compute the conversion time for the i^th sample (based on the number of samples and a conversion factor from ticks to milliseconds).

Comment: ADC in STM32 is fully deterministic and timing is descirbed in Reference Manual. Search for document RM0444 and check ADC section starting at page 343. It contains detailed how sequencing works, how to compute delays and so on. If you want to experimentaly check you can make experiment with settupuing precise timer for measuring time and starting DMA transaction making 150 conversions, record duration and then do the same experiment with changing 150 to 153. Substract measured times, divide by 3 and you get exactly how long do the measurement take with compensated overhead delays.

Comment: (1/2) Reply to previous non-related comment: 1V on UART TX line without configuration is not the STM32G0 chip bug. It is normal behaviour of all digital chips. By default (without configuration) are all pins configured as inputs which means that they are not driven to 0 (0V) nor 1 (3.3V) but instead they are "waiting" until someone else bring some voltage to them. Naturaly since pin is not tight to 0 or 3.3V you measure something between which comes from transistors characteristic. Measured voltage is sensitive to external sources like inductance from power outlet, radiation from space, ....

Comment: (2/2) Reply to previous non-related comment: if you want to resolve this behaviour you need to configure pin as output. If you need to make stable voltage when the MCU is off or unconfigured you need to provide external pull-up (or pull-down) resistor which will bring the desired voltage to the pin when nobody else (MCU) drives it..

Comment: @Misaz Thank you for your help! The UART issue was solved, and they ended up trusting the ADC CLK after all...